# Create GUI with "Select file" dialog in cpp, OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, user-interface

is there any way to enable user to select file manually using GUI in my cpp console application with OpenCV? I've made some research but found no solution for such trivial task so far...

Thanks in advance,
JP

Comment: not with the built in openCV functions

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! Well, I have to implement this functionality because the customer requested so...what would you recommend as the least painful way to do so?

Comment: Qt is a very good cross platform GUI library. Recently added support for Android and iOS too I believe

Comment: I would use Qt, opencv uses it for the gui display window anyway, it's relatively easy and cross platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you have to add any available gui library and handle the gui part with that keeping the image processing part to opnecv. ( For example, you can try Qt )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to a simple file open dialog in Ubuntu, you can do this:

```
FILE *in;
if (!(in = popen(
        "zenity  --title=\"Select an image\" --file-selection",
        "r"))) {
    return 1;
}

char buff[512];
string selectFile = "";
while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL) {
    selectFile += buff;
}
pclose(in);

//remove the "\n"
selectFile.erase(std::remove(selectFile.begin(), selectFile.end(), '\n'),
            selectFile.end());

// path + filename + format
Mat image = imread(selectFile);
```